# How to use Messages.app in OS X Lion forever

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, messaging

I received today an email from Apple stating Messages.app will not work anymore in OS X Lion by mid December. I do not want to update to Mountain Lion yet. Is it there some way to continue using Messages.app in OS X Lion?